# Is a variable declared in a for-loop's first statement scoped or treated specially?

Tags: javascript, syntax, binding, scope, specifications

Is there any (and I do mean any) difference between these two examples, as typed — even a subtle one?

```
for (var foo = 0; …; …)
    statement;
```

and

```
var foo = 0;
for (; …; …)
    statement;
```

I seem to remember some commentary I'd read that it behaves subtly differently, but as far as I can tell, the `foo` is still function-scoped in both cases. What's the difference?

(I tried to read through [ECMA-262 13.7.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-statement), but it ended up being a bit over my head.)

Comment: `foo` is still function-scoped in both cases, that's correct.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a difference.

```
for (var foo = something; …; …)
    statement;
```

is equivalent to:

```
var foo;                               // hoist foo (declare it at top)
for (foo = something; …; …)            // but doesn't assign the value at top, it will assign it where it was before the hoisting
    statement;
```

but not equivalent to:

```
var foo = something;                   // wrong assumption: it should not move the assignemet to top too, it should move just the declaration
for (; …; …)
    statement;
```

**Proof:**

**`1-`** If a variable isn't declared an error will be thrown:

```js
console.log(foo);
```

**`2-`** If a variable is never assigned a value, its value is `undefined`:

```js
var foo;

console.log(foo);
```

**`3-`** moves the declaration to top (hoisting) but not the assignment:

```js
console.log(foo); // undefined value but doesn't throw an error

var foo = "Hello, world!";
```

so it is equivalent to:

```js
var foo;  // declared first so it doesn't throw an error in the next line

console.log(foo);  // undefined so the assignment is still after this line (still at the same place before hoisting)

var foo = "Hello, world!";  // assignment here to justify the logged undefined value
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how the last two are different?

Comment: I still don't see how the 3rd example would be "wrong". That's certainly not wrong, just a different way of writing the same thing.

Comment: @Tomalak I meant **wrong assumption**: wrong of someone to think that that's how hoisting work. I'll reword the comment.

Comment: I'm aware of hoisting; I very specifically meant the example I typed: with no statement in between the assignment-statement, and the `for` statement. I'll improve the original question, thank you!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir In your extended examples you effectively say that `var foo = 'bar';` and `var foo; foo = 'bar';` are in fact equivalent. Yes, the assignment technically happens one step later, but in the case of a `for` loop it does not make any difference *at all*. `var i = 0; for (; i < 10; i++)` and `var i; for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)` (and even `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)`) are exactly the same thing for every conceivable practical purpose.

Comment: @Tomalak OP said  _... even a subtle one_  so details must be included carefully. The fact that  there is no other statements in between the declaration and the `for` loop makes all the above examples equivalent, but the way it trully works, only the first two are equivalent.

Comment: Fair enough, I acknowledge the academic difference.